# jQplot tooltip on click

Tags: jquery, mobile, jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

I'm using the jqplot's highlighter plugin at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/cursor-highlighter.php. As I am using it on mobile, I would like the tooltip to show on click/touch instead of on hover. Is there a way to do it?

I've tried changing

```
$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotMouseMove', handleMove]);
```

on the beginning of jqplot.highlighter.js to

```
$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotDataClick', handleMove]);
```

but with no sucess. Maybe I'm understanding the whole thing wrong?

(in the meanwhile, I found the solution: if you are using modernizr, replace the line above with:

```
var monitorTouch;

if($('html').hasClass('touch')) {
    monitorTouch = 'jqplotClick';
} else {
    monitorTouch = 'jqplotMouseMove';
}

$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push([monitorTouch, handleMove]);
```

This way, if your mobile device has touch enabled, the tooltip will activate on click; else, it will activate on mouseover.